# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {articles})

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, error-handling, state

This is my code.Where as when i try to build the component article as much as the value present. I am getting error stating *Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {articles}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.*

Eventhough the value at articles is array of objects.Its throwing this error when mapping.Should i import anything in this component or else is there any error in this code.This is the image of article values when i printed them in console--->[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPVoX.png)

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Article from './Article'

class Articles extends Component {
    state = {
      articles: [],
    }

  componentDidMount () {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
          this.setState({articles: response.data});
      });
  }
  render () {
    let articles = this.state.articles.map(article => {
      return <Article />;
    });
    return (
        {articles}
    );
  };
};

export default Articles;
```

Comment: You could try `{articles.length && articles}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing JavaScript objects curly braces, with JSX curly braces.

When you return `{ articles }`, you are actually returning an object that has a key called `articles`, with the list of `Article`s as a value.

It's equivalent to this:

```
render () {
  const list = this.state.articles.map(article => {
    return <Article />;
  });
  return (
    {articles: list}
  );
};
```

You just need to return `articles` instead:

```
render () {
  const articles = this.state.articles.map(article => {
    return <Article />;
  });
  return articles;
};
```

Using curly braces around `articles` would be correct if `articles` was used inside JSX:

```
render () {
  const articles = this.state.articles.map(article => {
    return <Article />;
  });
  return (
    <>{articles}</>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I just started working on react 3 days ago and was blocked by this for 4 hours and hoping to get resolved it asap..This did helped me lot..Again thank you so much..